# Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot not working in the production slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The switch is showing as successful in Azure, however when I check the app root files for the site these have not been swapped.
The process works on other slots just not the production one, can anyone think what the problem could be?

Many thanks David

Comment: How did you detect that there are no changes? Through the Kudu console?

Comment: I have found the same issue sometimes. I find if you rerun it many many times, it will sometimes work. I get the feeling that this is because the operation is triggered in Azure in an async way and sometimes it fails for whatever reason.